# flutter app create new instance when app resume

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am working on a meet app with [Jitsi meet](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet) in a flutter. it has two screens the first screen takes all the meeting details and the second screen is the meeting screen. The app has a picture in picture mode I turn off the pip mode.

When a meeting is ongoing I press the home button meeting is getting minimized (ongoing in the background) when I click on the app it does not take me back to the meeting instead it creates a new instance of the app on top of the background process this happens only the first time after installation on the app.

When I restart the app above issue is not anymore occurring (opening the app for a second time). for the second time When the app is minimized if I click on the app, it takes me back to the meeting.

Please help anyone know what is happing.

**Picture in Picture is Disabled in the latest changes.**
still the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use Services for fix app in foreground for first step.

Then, You can set it to what happen when user click on picture, in this way u can manage call in background and also sent him back to call screen like open a notification.

Example :

you receive a notification from some app, when u click on it, u will go to page what developer want.

I hope you get it, update me in comments.

Comment: and one more thing, set Single Instance in manifest of application.

Comment: i have tried single instance it kill the meeting which is going on in background and i have disabled the picture in picture mode. It creates instance on top of meeting if press back button in new instance it take me back to 1st on (to meeting). I can't redirect user because meeting code is directly loading jitsi plugin which is in react native.

Comment: The instance issue only occurring after installation when it starts the app for the second time the issue is not any more occurring it perfectly redirects me to meet if the meeting is going on. I have also raised the issue on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68760)